# Interface captions are too large while controls are small

Tags: gnome, display, display-resolution, scaling

I migrated my system to a laptop computer which has like double the screen resolution than my original laptop had (ThinkPad T400 1440x900 → ThinkPad W541 2880x1620). I didn't reinstall Ubuntu or anything, just transferred the hard drives. Now I have a unique problem that affects only some applications that captions are too large to fit, but controls (like checkboxes, radio buttons) are very small. Currently I'm on Ubuntu 21.04 with GNOME.

I kind of endured that until this point as it rarely caused problems, but now I have an application that is totally unusable due to this. Here is a screenshot to demonstrate:

[image: J.A.C.K. disproportionate interface]

(Another strange thing is that the window looks larger on the screenshot when I'm viewing it with 100% magnify than the real one looks like on my screen.)

Traditional GNOME applications (like Calculator, GEdit, etc.) are unaffected: captions and controls look normal, proportionate. Firefox is also unaffected. I think the problematic applications are those that don't use the GNOME libraries to render their user interface, but use something else instead, e.g. Qt. The ddrescueview program has the very same problem and the Steam interface is also rendered inconveniently small.

I checked my settings, I have screen scaling set to 200% (probably I set it after switching computers). Disabling it fixes the proportionate rendering of the problematic applications, but at the same time everything becomes hell small on screen (including said applications), so it's not a solution. It seems like the screen scaling is only partially applied to the applications those have the problem.

Comment: You have a common problem you can not just move the hard drive to another computer and expect no issues. Re install.

Comment: @David no, this is not MS Windows. Very unhelpful recommendation. Do some reconfiguration instead. Check GNOME Display settings and GNOME Tweaks first. MegaBrutal, which video adapters do you have in 1st and 2nd laptops? Does latter/new use Nvidia?

Comment: @David I won't reinstall an otherwise well-configured system I've been using for 7 years. I literally have no problem due to the migration aside from this one. It must be a configuration problem.

Comment: @N0rbert The former used Intel graphics, the latter has NVidia. Initially it was powered by the nouveau driver, later I installed the official proprietary NVidia driver to have better performance in video games. I have the new computer for like 1 year and the change of drivers didn't affect the problem. I think the problem is related to my scaling setting and also suspect the solution lies in GNOME Tweaks.

Comment: Good way to test is to create temporary new user and check look and feel of problematic applications there. I do not think that this problem is system-wide.